# How do I split a cell that goes over two rows into two cells, each containing its content?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to tidy up a dataset. It contains country names stretched over two lines. For easier analysis, I am trying to have each year correspond to one country.

[image]

This is what I am going for. Each cell contains one country.
[image]

Is there a function that would transform the above table to the table below?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no function I know of to do this, but you could do it with a relatively simple Google App Script ([overview and installation instructions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)). This script will unmerge all merged cells and replace empty cells with the value of the cell immediately above.

```
function unmergeAndExpand() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();

  // unmerge all of the cells in the sheet
  range.breakApart();

  var data  = range.getValues();
  var width = range.getLastColumn();

  // walk over your spreadsheet column by column
  for(var column = 0; column < width; column++){
    var last  = "";

    // walk down the rows
    for(var row = 0; row < data.length; row++){

      // if the current cell is empty and 
      if(last && ! data[row][column]){
        sheet.getRange(row+1, column+1).setValue( last );
      }

      // store the value of the current cell
      // so that we can fill the next cell, if it is empty
      last = data[row][column];
    }
  }
}
```